# Is there any way to split one part of the stacked bar vertically?

Tags: javascript, python, excel, vba, excel-2010

Original stacked bar

[image: Original stacked bar]

I am using Stacked Column to create balance sheet, and I want to let the Net assets part split to 2-3 vertically to point out Shareholder 1, 2, 3 with investment amount and name. Like the image below.

I want to do something like this
[image: I want to do something like this]

Is it possible to do this in Excel/VBA? Or I need to use other software? Or some web application provide this function?(or to write one by myself (by python or JS).

Thanks!